# Azure Continuous Deploy with Debug configuration

Tags: asp.net, git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Azure Continuous Deploy for an ASP.NET MVC project from a Bitbucket repository.
But it only publishes the site using **Release** settings.
How can I use Continuous Deploy with **Debug** settings or custom settings instead?

PS: I think that it doesn't matter, but I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Git tools for syncing with the Bitbucket repository

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can customize your deployment via a **.deployment** file in your repo ([details here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings)). E.g, you can change to DEBUG like so:

```
[config]
SCM_BUILD_ARGS=-p:Configuration=Debug
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Didn't know git deployment was so flexible. Thank you!

Comment: Note that due to a somewhat strange issue, it's important to use a dash instead of a slash for the switch. i.e. use -p and not /p

Comment: I had to remove the semicolon at the end for it to work.

Comment: What are the default options here? I'm happy to debug locally (very rarely do I need to debug on an azure app service in test). Will azure compile and optimize for a release build by default?